# Projeto compartilhado com CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Possuo um projeto com a seguinte extrutura:

```
Projeto A:
|   CMakeLists.txt
|   main.cpp
    | #include "ProjetoB/ClassB.cpp"
    | #include "ProjetoC/ClassC.cpp"
|   vendor/
        |   Projeto B:
            |   CMakeLists.txt
            |   ClassB.cpp
            |   Helper.h
        |   Projeto C:
            |   CMakeLists.txt
            |   ClassC.cpp
                |   #include "ProjetoB/Helper.h"
```

Meu Arquivo CMake do Projeto A está da seguinte forma:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(ProjetoA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(ProjetoA ${SOURCE_FILES})

MACRO(LINK_PROJECT_LIBRARY lib)
    target_link_libraries(ProjetoA ${lib})
ENDMACRO()

include_directories(vendor/ProjetoB/)
LINK_PROJECT_LIBRARY(ProjetoB)

include_directories(vendor/ProjetoC/)
LINK_PROJECT_LIBRARY(ProjetoC)
```

O meu problema começa comigo tentando incluir `#include "ProjetoB/Helper.h"` na ClassC, pois se eu não colocar esse include o cmake acha todas as dependências e compila bonitinho. Mas como eu preciso incluir ele não chega nem a achar o arquivo, tem como meus `include_directories` propagar para os demais cmake? Queria fazer um sistema de dependência um pouco mais dinâmico.

Comment: **(1)** está confuso...ProjetoB e ProjetoC são projetos mesmo ? geram uma lib ? no CMakeLists.txt dos projetos B e C existem comandos "add_library(ProjetoB)" e "add_library(ProjetoC)" ? ou na verdade só existe um "projeto", o Projeto A, que usa os fontes dos "projetos" B e C ? **(2)** outra coisa, acho estranho dois comandos "target_link_libraries"" para o Projeto A, pode até funcionar, não sei, mas o normal é a gente usar apenas um "target_link_libraries", e colocar as várias libs neste comando "target_link_libraries", ao invés de usar um comando "target_link_libraries" por lib

Comment: outra coisa que achei estranho: não deveria ter comandos "add_subdirectory(ProjetoB)" e "add_subdirectory(ProjetoC)" ?

Answer (score 0):

Não consigo ter uma ideia geral do seu projeto, mas de qualquer maneira vai uma sugestão de como eu faria, supondo que ProjetoB e ProjetoC geram duas libs que são utilizadas pelo projeto A...não testado, pode ter erros

ProjetoA/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(ProjetoA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

# INC_B e INC_C são exportados para os CMakeLists.txt dos sub-diretórios
set(INC_B vendor/ProjetoB)
set(INC_C vendor/ProjetoC)

add_subdirectory(ProjetoB)
add_subdirectory(ProjetoC)

add_executable(ProjetoA ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(ProjetoA ProjetoB ProjetoC)
```

ProjetoC/CMakeLists.txt

```
...
...
# em ClassC.cpp utilizar apenas '#include "Helper.h"'
include_directories(${INC_B})
...
...
add_library(ProjetoC classC.cpp)
...
...
```